# How do I compute the relative positions of a matrix elements?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, linear-algebra, graph-theory

Given a matrix A where an element A_ij, where means a line segment from point i to point j, and the value of A_ij is the **number of elements** on the right handed part of the line segment, how do I find if it is, true or false, that some element k is on the right side of a line segment from any point i to point j?

For example, if A_02 = 1 and there are 3 elements in total (0, 1, 2), then this means the line from element 0 to element 2 has 1 element on its right, which happens only if element 1 is on the right hand side of the line segment formed by elements 0 and 2. If given a query whether element 1 lies on the right of the traversal from element 0 to 2, the answer should be true.

To answer this question, here is my thought process:

1. This question vaguely resembles the problem of finding a convex-hull, where we want to find whether a third point is on the right hand side (and if so, we backtrack as seen in graham's scan).
2. However, in this case we don't have the geometric positions of the points, and so we're unable to perform the simple arithmetic that can determine whether a point is left of right of a line.
3. Given the above limitation, the information we have is the number of elements on the right. One can try going from some element A_ij to element A_jk and see if there is an element on the right, and keep on tracing until we reach a value of 0 (in which case we know the element is on the rightmost side).
4. But the above algorithm doesn't solve the case when there is a triadic closure i.e. the 3 points form a triangle, because then A_ij = 1, will lead to some A_jk = 1, which then again leads to A_ki = 1. This might result in non-termination of the algorithm.

Note: A_ii or A_ij where i=j (i.e. main diagonal of A) are all 0 since a line cannot be formed.

Is there a concept I should use to solve this problem or something that I'm missing?

I have the slightest faint intuition that a clever linear algebra trick might just solve the problem directly but I might be wrong.

Comment: Stupid question, but: If there are 4 Elements {0,1,2,3} and A_02 = 1. Is 1 or 3 right of A_02?

Comment: @leoderprofi That is the purpose of the question. The exact identity of the elements on the right side is not indicated except for the number of elements.

Comment: To make it clear: Matrix M = [[2,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,0]] would equal the line 012 ? Or what happens when i < j?

Comment: Also:
0123 equals 
[[3,2,1,0],[2,2,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]
and 0321 equals
[[3,0,1,2],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[2,0,1,3]]

Comment: I don't think i < j has any special meaning since it just means i and j are different elements. also to add, A_ii or A_ij where i=j  should be 0 since the line cannot be formed

Answer (score 0):

### Partial answer:

If an element `Aij = 0` with `i != j` then the segment `ij` is one of the convex hull. In other words, all the rest points lie to the left of the i-j segment.

If an element `Aij = n-2` with `i != j` then the segment `ij` is one of the convex hull. In other words, all the rest points lie to the right of the i-j segment.

If `Aij = 0` with `i != j` then `Aji = n-2`. Same segment, changed its orientation.

Because the matrix contains all possible segments, those of the convex hull included, for every point `k` there are always some segments for which the point lies at right of them. Namely, all segments of the convex hull (Aij=0 or Aij=n-2) that don't include the `k` point, chosen with the proper orientation.

So, to your question the answer is *true* for any `k`.

Knowing which is the segment closest to point k so that the point is at right of i-j is the tricky part.

For the case where a segment of the convex hull does not exist, you need a special value in the matrix (perhaps a negative value). In this case my logic is not valid.